# Apply CSS to first child and CSS to last child inside element but not if only child

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I'm looking for an elegant SASS solution to apply a style to the first child and a different style to the last one inside an element, but then no style if it's the only child.

How could I accomplish that?

An example would be:

- If the element is the first child in a `div`, give it a `margin-right` property of `5px`
- If the element is the last child in a `div`, give it a `margin-left` property of `5px
- If the element is an only child in a `div`, let `margin-right` and `margin-left` be `0`.

Imagine I had the following:

```
<div>
  <i>Item 1</i>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <i>Item 3</i>
</div>
```

- I'd expect `Item 1` to have a `margin-right` property of `5px`, `margin-left` should be `0`.
- I'd expect `Item 2` to have no styles applied to it.
- I'd expect `Item 3` to have a `margin-left` property of `5px`, `margin-right` should be `0`.

If I had this example:

```
<div>
  <span>Item</span>
</div>
```

- I'd expect `Item` to have no styles applied to it

I've tried something like this:

```
div {
  i {
    &:first-child {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    &:last-child {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work if I have the case:

```
<div>
  <i>Item 1</i>
  <span>Item 2</span>
</div>
```

Because `Item 1` has both `margin-right` and `margin-left` properties set to `5px` when I actually want `margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 0;`.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm a little rusty on my CSS-Selectors.

Comment: could you check twice your last example? Item1 can't have a margin-left applied with the given code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a condition when the node it's the only child

```
div {
  > * {
    &:first-child {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    &:last-child {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
    &:only-child {
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to your SASS rule could give your the result you want. Try the following SASS rule.

```
div {
  i {
    &:first-of-type {
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    &:last-child {
      margin-left: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```